# How to get all words in the buffer with at least 2 characters starting with some characters?

Tags: vim

**Foreword**

I know there is `match()`, `matchstr()` and so on but it seems there is no function which returns all matches in a string (not sub-matches). It is possible to deal with `matchstrpos()` but there is big overhead parsing regex every time. That is why I use `split()` function for performance related tasks.

**The goal**

I need to find all words in the buffer with at least 2 characters starting with "text". The pattern is quite simple. For instance, to find all words starting with "f" I use `f\w\+` but I do not know how to inverse the pattern to pass into `split()` function. Right now I use `\W` and then filter words with `filter()` function. I think the algorithm could be faster.

**Current code**

```
function! completion#filter(base, lastIndex, i, word)
    return a:word[1] != "" && a:word[0:a:lastIndex] ==# a:base

    " also tried this
    " return a:word[1] != "" && strridx(a:word, a:base, 0) == 0
endfunction

let words = split(join(getline(1, "$"), "\n"), '\W\+')
call filter(words, funcref("completion#filter", [a:base, len(a:base) - 1]))
```

Comment: maybe it would help if you post your current code...

Comment: Well, the code is here.

Comment: so in the end you want a list with all the words ?

Comment: Yes, I need a list. Perhaps somehow iterate over `/` command result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is taken from here:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/is-it-possible-to-get-the-matched-string-after-calling-search

Please consider leaving an upvote there!

The basic trick is `:s\=` (`:h :s\=`) combined with `:s//n` (`:h :s`).

`:s\=` allows us to evaluate vimscript in a `:s//` command, while the `n` flag allows us to skip an actuall substition.

So in the easiest form it could be uses like this:

```
let b = [] | execute ':keeppatterns %s/f\w\+/\=add(b, submatch(0))/gn' | echo b
```

as you can see, you now have a list with all the searchresult.

In the link above you can find a general solution, which takes a function as argument.

Comment: However, there is very strange issue. Calling `add` function causes huge overhead comparison to search. In my `.vimrc` currently 800 lines and search takes 1ms when there are no matches. But when there are only 700 matches the command takes imposing **100ms**.

Comment: @Evgeniy you could try to improve your answer with a `:g//p` before the `split`. But i don't know if it is faster then what i posted